# Detecting Removable drive letter in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, removable-storage, drive-letter

I'm trying to write a script, which will detect the letter of my USB Removable Drive called "UUI" and then create folder on it. I've written few commands for CMD which, when run separately, work. However when I put them into a bat file, I always get some errors. Here are the commands in a bat file:

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %i in ('WMIC logicaldisk where "DriveType=2" list brief ^| c:\windows\system32\find.exe "UUI"') do (echo %i > drive.txt)
set /p RemovableDriveLetter2= < drive.txt
del /F /Q drive.txt
set RemovableDriveLetter=%RemovableDriveLetter2:~0,1%
%RemovableDriveLetter%:
md MyNewFolder
cd MyNewFolder
```

When I go to cmd.exe and run the file by calling "myScript.bat" or "call myScript.bat", I get an error:

> C:\Users\UUI\Desktop>myScript.bat
>
> \windows\system32\find.exe was unexpected at this time.
>
> C:\Users\UUI\Desktop>for /F "tokens=1 delims= " \windows\system32\find.exe "UUI"') do (echo i > drive.txt)
>
> C:\Users\UUI\Desktop>

I can see that MyNewFolder was not created. However, when I copy all lines and run them in CMD as such (e.g. not in the .bat file) and run them one by one, it is fully functional within the cmd.exe instance.

How can I create bat a file, which will successfully run and detects the drive letter of my removable drive without issues? Or how can I solve the error "\windows\system32\find.exe was unexpected at this time."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *double* the `%` sign used to mark a `FOR` loop control variable in a batch script (`.bat` or `.cmd`), i.e. use `%%i` instead of `%i` used in pure CLI.

However, there is another possible approach how-to parse `wmic` output. 
See also Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions
set "USBCounter=0"
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('
    WMIC logicaldisk where "DriveType=2" get DeviceID /value 2^>NUL ^| find "="
') do for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ("%%G") do (
    set /A "USBCounter+=1"
    echo %%i
    rem your stuff here
)
echo USBCounter=%USBCounter%
rem more your stuff here
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

Here the `for` loops are

- `%%G` to retrieve the `DeviceID` value;
- `%%i` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned: `wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (`CR+CR+LF`) instead of common `0x0D0A` (`CR+LF`).

One could use `Caption` or `Name` instead of `DeviceID`:

```
==>WMIC logicaldisk where "DriveType=2" get /value | find ":"
Caption=F:
DeviceID=F:
Name=F:
```

Note there could be *no* or *more* disks present having `DriveType=2`:

```
==>WMIC logicaldisk where "DriveType=2" get /value | find ":"
No Instance(s) Available.

==>WMIC logicaldisk where "DriveType=2" list brief
DeviceID  DriveType  FreeSpace   ProviderName  Size        VolumeName
F:        2          2625454080                3918512128  HOMER
G:        2          999600128                 1029734400  LOEWE
```

Script **output** for *no*, then *one* and then *two* USB drive(s), respectively:

```
==>D:\bat\SO\31356732.bat
USBCounter=0

==>D:\bat\SO\31356732.bat
F:
USBCounter=1

==>D:\bat\SO\31356732.bat
F:
G:
USBCounter=2

==>
```

Comment: Very good answer! I have just one hint: `^| find "="` in first batch code is not necessary as __FOR__ ignores the empty UTF-16 LE encoded lines interpreted wrong as a line with just a carriage return because of these lines have no second token which could be assigned to the loop variable `G`. So it is not necessary to filter out the empty lines with `find`.