# how to assign output from command to variable in command prompt

Tags: variables, cmd, drive-letter

I have these two commands

`C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp>WMIC LOGICALDISK where volumename="abc" get deviceid>%temp%/path.txt`

which creates file *path.txt* with content:

```
DeviceID
F:
```

the file has lots of additional spaces which I have added in the above file^

I then use (although I know I could use the | char I am trying to avoid it) the command
`C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp>FINDSTR [:] path.txt>path2.txt` which gives the output  `F :`    which is incredibly frustrating as I obviously just need the "F"/alphabetic char that would be in its position and store it in a variable.

Could someone please show me how to do this - or ultimately get the drive letter of a usb device using cmd only and store it in a variable?

I don't mind if it takes a lot of lines just no | char please or quote marks " :)

edit: it MUST be in command prompt and can be written line by line (no cop and paste commands) and I need the individual letter (eg. F:) by itself - stored in a variable or the clip board. and obviously, no pipe character or quote marks pls :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting Removable drive letter in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356732/detecting-removable-drive-letter-in-cmd)

Comment: There can be used __in a batch file__ `for /F "tokens=2 delims==:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK where VolumeName^="abc" GET DeviceID /VALUE 2^>nul') do set "DriveLetter=%%I"` to (re)define the environment variable `DriveLetter` with the just the letter of the drive of the volume with name `abc`. Replace all `%%` by just `%` for usage in a command prompt window.

Comment: For a full explanation of a similar command line see [How to get the drive letter of a drive with a specific drive name on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62830106/3074564)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*No `|` char please :)* I think you mean the [*pipe* character](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) `|` (U+007C,  *Vertical Line*)?

Batch file (set a desired string to the `_volume` variable instead of *my debugging value* `Elements`):

```
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL
rem set the variable _volume and delete the variable _letter
set "_volume=Elements"
set "_letter="

for /F "tokens=2 delims==:" %%G in ('
  WMIC LOGICALDISK where volumename^="%_volume%" get deviceid/Value
') do set "_letter=%%G"

echo letter of volume "%_volume%" is "%_letter%"
```

**Output**: `.\SO\71753240.bat`

```
letter of volume "Elements" is "F"
```

Command prompt (copy and paste the following code snippet into an open `cmd.exe` window):

```
set "_volume=Elements"
set "_letter="
for /F "tokens=2 delims==:" %G in ('WMIC LOGICALDISK where volumename^="%_volume%" get deviceid/Value') do @set "_letter=%G"
@echo letter of volume "%_volume%" is "%_letter%"
```

Note that `wmic` output redirected to a file is `UTF-16-BOM`:

```
WMIC LOGICALDISK where volumename="%_volume%" get deviceid>%temp%\path71753240.txt
hexdump.exe -H %temp%\path71753240.txt
```

> ```
> 000000  ff fe 44 00 65 00 76 00 69 00 63 00 65 00 49 00  ..D.e.v.i.c.e.I.
> 000010  44 00 20 00 20 00 0d 00 0a 00 46 00 3a 00 20 00  D. . .....F.:. .
> 000020  20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 0d 00   . . . . . . ...
> 000030  0a 00
> ```

Comment: hi thanks for your response, i do indeed mean the pip character. however, I must be able to run it in command prompt not a batch file and it cant be a copy and paste job - my apologies I will edit the question now. I tried the bottom method you put in cmd and it side 'hexdump.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. - not sure if I have done something weird there. please advice :)

Comment: Just type `for /F "tokens=2 delims==:" %G in ('WMIC LOGICALDISK where volumename^="abc" get deviceid/Value') do @set "_letter=%G"`. And forget that note about `wmic` output redirected to a file… BTW, you could download (useful utility) `hexdump.exe` from https://www.di-mgt.com.au/hexdump-for-windows.html

Comment: omg it actually finally worked thank you so much :)))

Comment: im sorry but is there anyway you could do it without using the " quote character as well please?

Comment: @kidders *do it without using the `"` quote character* ```for /F usebackq^ tokens^=2^ delims^=^=^: %G in (`WMIC LOGICALDISK where volumename^='abc' get deviceid/Value`) do @echo _letter=%G``` returns `_letter=F` (see https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)